# effective java builder idiom equivalent in c++?

Tags: java, c++, design-patterns

This is a great idiom I've been using since reading Effective Java.  I've been trying to find a C++ equivalent or something similar and have had little luck.  The traditional builder pattern found in the GoF book isn't really applicable in my case.  It's one complicated object that has a very messy constructor.  Below is a small implementation of the Java.

```
class ComplicatedObject {

    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private int      field3;

    private ComplicatedObject(Builder builder) {

            this.field1 = builder.myField1;
            this.field2 = builder.myField2;
            this.field3 = builder.myField3;

    }

    public static class Builder {

            private String myField1 = "some default";
            private String myField2 = "some other default";
            private int           myField3 = -1;

            public Builder() { }
            public Builder field1(String val) {
                    this.myField1 = val;
                    return this;
            }
            public Builder field2(String val) {
                    this.myField2 = val;
                    return this;
            }
            public Builder field3(int val) {
                    this.myField3 = val;
                    return this;
            }
            public ComplicatedObject build() {
                    return new ComplicatedObject(this);
            }
    }
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
    //built like this

            ComplicatedObject obj = new ComplicatedObject.Builder().field1("blah").field2("lol").field3(4).build();

    }
}
```

Comment: You can do this with almost no modification in C++ (just use references as the return type for the methods of the `Builder` class).

Comment: Mike, and every year we build a layer on top of those layers built last year.... But if you are still into it, check this out - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#C.2B.2B

Comment: @VladLazarenko I looked at that initially, but the process of building an object by function chaining tends to be the best approach when you're not designing a family of objects, but instead just 1 object that has a lot of user configurable member variables

Comment: @Mike: Strongly disagree. Just create that object and assign fields one by one. Why the hell do you need to put it trough "builder" class... Well, unless you are paid per line of code.

Comment: @Vlad strongly disagree :) The idea behind builder is primarily to allow the constructor to construct a complete object. The `SomeClass s = new SomeClass(); s.setAttr1(..); s.setAttr2(..)` etc is essentially appropriate for plain old data objects and an abomination in OO IMHO.

Comment: This builder implementation is very complicated. Why do you set fields in the builder and pass it in a constructor to the ComplicatedObject? This kinda reverses responsibility and makes your ComplicatedOject depending on the builder which makes no sense!

Comment: @Vlad oops I take that back...the Design Pattern Builder pattern is not quite the Builder pattern in vogue these days; specifically it does not mention fluent interface. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @HemalPandya I completely agree with you.  Having ten+ lines of code that are essentially Object.setSomething() is subversive to OOP

Comment: The advantages of the Builder pattern have been well-documented (look up the telescoping constructor pattern) but like anything, the Builder pattern may not be suitable for every case. If you are building a bullet-proof API for a popular library like Google's Guava, you should use it. Joshua Bloch explains the advantages in detail in this article: http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/creating-and-destroying-java-objects-par/208403883?pgno=2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not only can it be adapted to C++ but rather the idiom has been adapted **from** C++.

I think the first time I heard of this idiom was before Java came into existence. IIRC Bjarne Stroustrup mentions this in C++ 2nd Edition as an explanation of why C++ does not need Smalltalk style named parameters.

I could have my dates wrong but this is about 15 years old in C++.

EDIT: It seems it wad first described in **Design and Evolution of C++** (6.5.1) where it was called **named function parameters**

Comment: +1: I believe `Builder` is one of the original http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns which had examples in `C++` and `smalltalk`.

Comment: Thanks @PeterLawrey. If it was in the original GoF book then it was already prior art in 1994 :)

Comment: I am not convinced this is the first time a builder pattern was ever used in any language, but clearly examples in C++ pre date Java and have been championed by C++'s designer.

Comment: @Peter agree completely...I don't see why it would not have been used before, though I myself don't have previous experience. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Peter Lawrence: Ofc it is not the first time that they ever where used! But it was the first time they got gatherd in a book and named! The GoF book very often gives references where the pattern was found/discoverd and used before, e.g. in the ET++ library (C++ library) or at Taligent Inc. or PARC etc.

Comment: @Angel and Peter the GoF [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) is not quite same as the Builder pattern in vogue today; specifically it does not use Fluent Interface that the named function parameters uses. The GoF stuff is practically unrelated. Not to say that Fluent Interface was not used before Stroustrup wtote about it.

Comment: Depends what _you_ mean with builder pattern. From my mind I'm not sure if the GoF examples whre fluent or not, but my implementations at that time always where. However a StringBuilder in Java is certainly not an example for the builder pattern, if that is the point you want to make.

Comment: @Angel you are correct. Fluent Interface is not essential to Builder pattern and StringBuilder is certainly not builder in that sense. Not sure what you mean by "my implementations at that time always where (were?)". All I was saying was that the builder pattern is derived from Named Parameters idiom.

Comment: @Hemal Pandya, hm I would not agree to your point regarding "Named Parameters Idiom". After all they have complete different goals. The idiom is used to express more clearly what the parameters are supposed to mean, and being able to change the order. The builder pattern is seperating the structure from the construction process. With the opotion to exchange parts of the construction process, or better vary the constructed parts. Patterns are allways a level higher than Idioms anyway. So many patterns may be variations / combinations of the same Idioms.

Comment: According to Bloch, the Builder pattern is a form of the GoF Builder pattern : "Luckily, there is a third alternative that combines the safety of the telescoping constructor pattern with the readability of the JavaBeans pattern. It is a form of the Builder pattern [Gamma95, p. 97]. " http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/creating-and-destroying-java-objects-par/208403883?pgno=2

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class ComplicatedObject {
    public: class Builder {
            friend class ComplicatedObject;

            private: string myField1;
            private: string myField2;
            private: int    myField3;

            public: Builder()
                    : myField1("some default"),
                     myField2 ("some other default"),
                     myField3(-1)
            { }
            public: Builder& field1(const string& val) {
                    myField1 = val;
                    return *this;
            }
            public: Builder& field2(const string& val) {
                    myField2 = val;
                    return *this;
            }
            public: Builder& field3(int val) {
                    myField3 = val;
                    return *this;
            }
            public: ComplicatedObject build() {
                    return ComplicatedObject(*this);
            }
    };

    private: string field1;
    private: string field2;
    private: int      field3;

    private: ComplicatedObject(const Builder& builder) 
            :field1(builder.myField1),
            field2(builder.myField2),
            field3(builder.myField3)
    {}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc < 4) {
        std::cout << "not enough params.";
        return 1;
    }
    ComplicatedObject obj(ComplicatedObject::Builder().field1("blah").field2("lol").field3(4));

}
```

I made minimal changes to make it C++, fast, and safe.  http://ideone.com/sCH1V