# Initializing member data of pointer type to NULL in constructor that uses Builder Pattern

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, null, builder

I have a constructor which uses an internal `Builder` object to instantiate a complex object. Five of the members in the data structure are of pointer types. However, using this pattern I am running into problems when the object is destroyed. The following is what my constructor looks like, with member initialization list:

```
Player::Player(const Builder& builder) 
    :m_name(builder._name)
    ,m_description(builder._description)
    ,m_primaryAttributes(builder._primaryAttributes)
    ,m_abilityAttributes(builder._abilityAttributes)
    ,m_armor(builder._armor)
    ,m_weapon(builder._weapon)
    ,m_inventory(new ComponentMap())
{}
```

The client code works well, as expected:

```
Player* player = Player::Builder()
    .name("Dylan")
    .description("Super bad-ass hero of the game")
    .primaryAttributes(createPrimaryAttributes())
    .abilityAttributes(createAbilityAttributes())
    .weapon(createWeapon())
    .armor(createArmor())
    .build();
```

However, if I omit one of the arguments in the message chain, and then destroy my `Player` object, bad stuff happens:

```
Player* player = Player::Builder()
    .name("Dylan")
    .description("Super bad-ass hero of the game")
    .primaryAttributes(createPrimaryAttributes())
    .abilityAttributes(createAbilityAttributes())
    .armor(createArmor())
    .build();

// ...

delete player;

// ...

// cleanMemory() gets called in Player::~Player()
void Player::cleanMemory()
{
    if(m_primaryAttributes != NULL )
        delete m_primaryAttributes;
    if(m_abilityAttributes != NULL )
        delete m_abilityAttributes;
    if(m_inventory != NULL )
        delete m_inventory;
    if(m_weapon != NULL)          // oops, bad stuff happens here
        delete m_weapon;
    if(m_armor != NULL)
        delete m_armor;
}
```

Clearly, this happens because the pointer for weapon didn't get initialized to either `NULL` or an instance of `Weapon` object. The constructor also doesn't appear to allow for a default of `NULL` (at least from what I can see) in the event that one `Builder` method is omitted from the chain. For now, the client must either give `Weapon` a pointer to `NULL` or an instance of an object.

Is there any possible way to get around this without revising this `Builder` constructor completely? Or, should this be refactored using another pattern, such as `Factory`, and just go back to a regular constructor with positional parameter list?

Comment: please could show us `Player::Builder` function?

Comment: My first thought was smart pointers. That would completely eliminate cleanMemory().

Comment: I want to see the constructor for `Builder`.

Comment: @Mooing Duck and @billz: The constructor for `Builder` is just the default constructor, but now that you mention it I see now that I can probably initialize the values of pointer type there. Thanks.

Comment: I am very curious how this call is possible, that's why I want to see the source code. `Player* player = Player::Builder()
    .name("Dylan")
    .description("Super bad-ass hero of the game")
    .primaryAttributes(createPrimaryAttributes())
    .abilityAttributes(createAbilityAttributes())
    .weapon(createWeapon())
    .armor(createArmor())
    .build();`

Comment: @billz: I won't reproduce it above, but it is very much the same as this `Builder` pattern in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520250/effective-java-builder-idiom-equivalent-in-c

Comment: Just a side note. There is no need to check for `NULL` before doing `delete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sample code you referred isn't very good code base, I would simply suggest below `build pattern`:

```
class Builder
{
   Weapon* BuildWeapon() { return new Weapon(); }
   Armor*  BuildArmor(); { return new Armor(); }    
};

class Player
{
public:
  Player(const Builder& builder) 
  : weapon_ptr(builder.BuildWeapon()),
    armer_ptr(builder.BuildArmor())

private:
  std::shared_ptr<Weapon> weapon_ptr;
  std::shared_ptr<Armor>  armor_ptr;
};
```

usage:

```
Builder builder;
std::shared_ptr<Player> player(new Player(builder));
```

Or you could just

```
class Player2
{
public:
  Player() {}
  void SetWeapon(Weapon* p) { weapon_ptr.reset(p); }
  void SetArmor(Armor* p) { armor_ptr.reset(p); }

private:
  std::shared_ptr<Weapon> weapon_ptr;
  std::shared_ptr<Armer>  armer_ptr;
};
```

usage:

```
   Builder builder;
   std::shared_ptr<Player> player;
   player->SetWeapon(builder.BuildWeaper());
   player->SetArmor(builder.BuildArmor());
```

As weapon_ptr, armer_ptr are smart pointers, there is no need to call `delete` for the dynamically allocated memory anymore, thus `cleanMemory()` function can be removed.

This is just a simple sample, you could expand the Player's interfaces to provide ability to build different element after player object is created.

Comment: Thanks. In my previous implementation, I used the `Builder` in its own class as you suggested above, instead of nested within the `Player` class. However, my current solution uses a `Builder` interface, whereby each complex object I have uses its own nested Builder, which implements the `Builder` interface. This way I can encapsulate `Builder` functionality in each class that requires it without having to instantiate a `Builder` object each time I want to create a complex object. I will run with your idea using the smart pointer, though.

Comment: to pass in Builder object into Player construtor or not is a minimal issue, it'a small design style change.